# Regex pattern not working in a particular case

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to clean a cms database: all the contents have inline style and I need to strip them.

I have a lot of nested tag, so I'm trying to replace `<span>` tag with `<h3>` (I'm sure that the titles are not nested) and then with HTMLPurifier I'll clean other tags.

I write this line to replace `<span>` tag with `<h3>`:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/<span style="line-height: 17pt; font-family: helvetica; color: rgb\(85, 85, 85\); font-size: 13pt; font-weight: bold;">(.*?)<\/span>/', '<h3>$1</h3>',$string);
```

It works in every situation exept for this:

```
<span style="line-height: 17pt; font-family: helvetica; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-size: 13pt; font-weight: bold;">"Rischio obsolescenza" per i lettori Blu-ray</span>
```

Maybe the " in the text are the problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

No, the quotes aren't the problem, and the regex does match in my tests. Are you sure you don't have a newline somewhere in-between, because the dot does not match them unless you use the `/s` modifier. So, please try

```
$string = preg_replace( '/<span style="line-height: 17pt; font-family: helvetica; color: rgb\(85, 85, 85\); font-size: 13pt; font-weight: bold;">(.*?)<\/span>/s', '<h3>$1</h3>',$string);
```